# Change alignment of a string in a particular cell in Excel with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data in my Excel sheet:

| Course code |
| --- |
| Digi- External & Internal |
| Digi- External & Internal |
| Digi- External & Internal |
| Fire and safety |

If you select that particular cell then you will notice that the line digi external and internal is written in two lines like - **Digi- External &** in top line and in bottom line **Internal** is written

I have tried

```
df['col'].replace(' ','_',regex=True)
```

Assuming removing spaces with underscore would bring that in one line but still it won't work

When I tried to work on pandas

Trying to create pivot table with individual values in rows

```
df=df[['fire and safety','Digi- External & Internal']]
```

throws an error

> key error Digi- External & Internal not in index

I hope I have made clear what my problem is. Please help if anyone knows..Thanks in advance

Comment: check the df index before further investigation by `df.info(verbose=True)`

Comment: `is written in two lines` - it means in one cell? Or in 2 cells? Because sample data in question are in one cell without this problem

Comment: Jezrael it is written in one cell but in this form like Digi- External & (suppose after & you have pressed enter button) Internal

Comment: @RedVibes - Just tested and if one cell I got `Digi- External & \nInternal` - here `\n` is for new line. In your data is too `\n` ?

Comment: Jezrael yes exactly internal is written in new line...but both is written in one cell

Comment: There is `\n` ?

Comment: Jezrael space is there...not \n this

Comment: What is your pandas version? Is possible upgrade?

Comment: Jezrael I have checked in jupyter it shows 1.1.3

Comment: Amir Maleki it shows error Attribute error series'object has no attribute info

Comment: @RedVibes - Is possible create excel file only with one column and 1-2 rows with problematic data and share it? Because this problem is data relevant and cannot simulate it. You can share it by `dropbox`, gdocs, wetransfer...

Comment: jezrael ok give me few minutes I will share my data in we transfer

Comment: @RedVibes - super, please share only relevant rows, all not relevant remove.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9d8400ad83a946146bf85284fedf7af220210217104940/59a04a

Comment: Sir I have added the link of we transfer